# How to alter databasechangelog.filename for Spring Boot and Liquibase?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.1 and `liquibase-core-3.5.5`.

When I run the application from IntelliJ (which will run the `main()` method) I see the following type of value in the Liquibase database column `database.filename`:

```
db/changelog/changes/v0001.sql
```

If I create a fat jar with embedded Tomcat and run the application, the same changeset will appear in the database as:

```
BOOT-INF/classes/db/changelog/changes/v0001.sql
```

I would like these values to match so that I can run my applications as JAR files, but connect to a remote database from IntelliJ if debugging is necessary. (Note: this would be for a test database, I would not debug production in this way).

I have found references to `logicalFilePath` (such as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896436/how-to-configure-liquibase-not-to-include-file-path-or-name-for-calculating-chec)), but I don't believe this will provide what I need.

I have also tried debugging into the Liquibase code to determine if there is a way I can alter this value. The closest I've come is these two observations:

1. The absolute file path of the SQL file trimmed to its final value [here.](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/ff5d7842ab73b90642582f27fddf3eb91088a863/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/resource/AbstractResourceAccessor.java#L110)
2. The full set of changes being persisted is available [here](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/08ab364d946270191d101455065ccf55028e8723/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/yaml/YamlChangeLogParser.java#L80). And if I change one of those values (while debugging), I can see that it makes it into the database.

If there is a way to make these consistent, or possibly just change the `filename` column to the actual filename (e.g. `v0001.sql`), that would be best.

**UPDATE**

I have Liquibase setup as the following in Spring Boot:

My `resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml` file has the following contents:

```
databaseChangeLog:
    - includeAll:
        path: db/changelog/changes/
```

And then in `resources/db/changelog/changes` I have individual `*.sql` files that contain the SQL I want to run. I do not recall where I found this setup, but I don't have anything specific to "changesets", is this an error on my part?

Comment: Can you expand on why you think the `logicalFilePath` attribute won't provide what you need? If I understand Liquibase correctly, solving your issue is exactly what that attribute was designed for.

Comment: @SteveDonie I could definitely be mistaken (which would be great). I wasn't able to find much information on `logicalFilePath`, and when I tried testing it out (in `db.changelog-master.yaml`) it didn't seem to have any affect on `databasechangelog.filename`.

Comment: hi,  I have a same issue =(
Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @ykembayev sadly I have not had a chance to get back to this. I'll respond when/if I get this figured out.

Comment: @ykembayev I have posted an answer of how I was able to fix this. Hopefully it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to use this by no longer using the `includeAll` option in my `db.changelog-master.yaml` file. The `includeAll` option is a helpful way to get started quickly (and process all files in a specific directory), but it seems to be unadvisable for regular use. As mentioned [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/includeall.html).

This is what I previously had in `db.changelog-master.yaml`, **don't use it this way**.

```
databaseChangeLog:
    - includeAll:
        path: db/changelog/changes/
```

This is what I updated it to:

```
databaseChangeLog:
    - include:
        file: db/changelog/changes/v0001_users.sql
    - include:
        file: db/changelog/changes/v0002_accounts.sql
```

The important thing to note is that I'm specifically listing every single file that I want included, in the order I want it run. This is a little bit of a hassle, but well worth the change.

In the original version, the `databasechangelog.filename` column would be different based on how the application was executed:

- `db/changelog/changes/v0001_users.sql` is how the column would appear when running from IntelliJ
- `BOOT-INF/classes/db/changelog/changes/v0001_users.sql` is how the column would appear when running from an executable jar.

After making the change, both options above are the same, and no longer include `BOOT-INF/classes/` as a prefix.

Thanks to the other answers that helped point me in the correct direction!

Comment: `this is a little bit of a hassle, but well worth the change.`

For large projects with hundreds of files, this becomes unmanageable, unfortunately. This seems like it's actually a bug - why would `includeAll` and `include` behave differently? And why does it run differently from an IDE than it does from a jar?

Comment: @arrowman If you find a better solution, please add an answer here so we can all learn from it. Thanks.

Comment: I also think change `include` is not a good idea, It's difficult to find the correspondence between the configuration file and the actual file when there are many files.

Answer (score 3):

The `logicalFilePath` attribute is exactly what you want. I was facing same issue with my projects where I was executing some parts with maven and some parts with spring-boot. 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061247/liquibase-changeset-how-to-use-alternative-unique-identifier-for-a-changeset) can also help you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've updated my question. Is it possible to run this without changeset files, but rather using "inclueAll" in my yaml properties file? Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand that question, but if you would like to run all sql files which are in folder `../changes` you are good to go with this setup. But suggest you to change the logic and don't use includeAll. It has plenty of disadvantages. Read [this](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/includeall.html) and part in warning

Answer (score 2):

Set `logicalFilePath` on every single changeset. This will ensure that the `DATABASECHANGELOG.FILENAME` column is consistent and doesn't depend on your physical checkout directory of the changeset file, [as explained in this post](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/logical-filepath-in-change-sets-and-changelog#49382000000033315).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've updated my question. Is it possible to run this without changeset files, but rather using "inclueAll" in my yaml properties file? Thanks.